# Why does linux binary crashes with segmentation fault when run on other distro?

Tags: c++, linux, server, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries

The system where I compile the executable is based on arch linux. Now I want to upload the compiled binary to my server with not root access (so I cannot install any further libraries, without compiling them myself), which is based on CentOS. The easiest application

`#include <iostream>
int main() { 
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl; 
}`

compiled on my own computer runs without problems on the CentOS server.

When I need more libraries (like boost) I have to upload all the .so files from my computer to the server, which are displayed when running `ldd a.out`, so the program can find them with (I did not place them in any system folders):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/.../lib/ /home/.../bin/a.out
```

The ldd command displayed following libraries, which I uploaded all without linux-vdso.so.1:

```
linux-vdso.so.1
libboost_system.so.1.63.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.63.0 
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6
librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
```

But when I compile the example program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
int main() {
  boost::mutex mutex;
  mutex.lock();
  mutex.unlock();    
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

with `g++ file.cpp -lboost_system` and run it with right LD_LIBRARY_PATH it crashes on my server with a segmentation fault. I ran the executable on other arch distros and shipped my library files with the program and it worked without problems.

Debugging the program on the server with gdb is not so easy, because gdb cannot find the right libraries for the program I uploaded and when starting gdb with the right LD_LIBRARY_PATH it crashes of course, because it needs the system libraries not mine.

The only solution I know is linking all the libraries static. But the first problem with this is, that I dont have the static versions of some libraries, so I have to compile them myself, but this is for several reasons not what I want to do.

I think, that there must be an easierer solution, than linking the program static. Also it would be a big help understanding, why the program crashes with a segmentation fault.

**This solved the problem for me**

I had to compile the file with the mentioned `-Wl,-rpath` by one answer and also with `-Wl,-dynamic-linker`:

```
g++ file.cpp -Wl,-rpath=<path to libs> -Wl,-dynamic-linker,<path to libs>/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -lboost_system
```

The problem was, that my executable used the ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 from the other system and not mine.

Comment: If you really "uploaded" libstdc++.so, as you claimed, congratulations: you totally borked the entire server that you "uploaded" this library to, by overwriting the existing one which was most likely a different C++ library that all existing software on that server depends on. Oy vey, and you also "uploaded" libc.so. Well, I guess it's time to completely wipe and reinstall that server, I suppose...

Comment: Thats not true, because only my program can find the libraries, because I use LD_LIBRARY_PATH only for my program and my own libraries are not located in any system folders. Also I dont have root access, so I cannot destroy anything.

Comment: That wasn't very clear. `ldd` is not going to show any libraries that get `dlopen`ed at runtime. `libc` does dlopen some libraries; don't know about boost. Run your executable with strace to see the real list of libraries that get opened at runtime, and go from there. But, generally, Linux is not very friendly to binary-only packages. Linux is designed for free software, with software being distributed in source form, and individually compiled for each Linux platform. You're swimming against the tide, here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try with strace and copy the libraries from there. It is true that I am "swimming against the tide", but compiling the libraries on the server and my own application is a bit rude, because the server is shared with other users.

Comment: You may want to read up on the [-rpath](https://www.google.dk/amp/s/enchildfone.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/a-description-of-rpath-origin-ld_library_path-and-portable-linux-binaries/amp/) linker option.

Comment: Thank you all very much! It works now with "g++ file.cpp -Wl,-rpath=../lib -lboost_system -Wl,-dynamic-linker,../lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"